# SSRS not to email when no data in Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are using SSRS 2008 R2. In which have created a subscription for emailing the report but don't want to send the report when it has no data, as our subscription will run every hour. Please can anyone let me know that how can I prevent a blank report or a report with no data from emailing?

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this using a stored procedure and data driven subscription.

1. create a stored procedure that will return the subscription information needed (from address, to address, email body, etc)
2. Have the stored procedure check if data exists in your query
3. use an "if" statement to return a blank or dummy email address when no data exists.
4. USe the stored procedure as the source for the data driven subscription.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Enterprise Edition, look into [Data Driven Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx). (This is also in Developer Edition.)

If you are using any other edition of SQL Server then this is not possible without writing [code to manipulate the subscriptions](http://tech-motive.blogspot.com/2009/04/programmatically-playing-with-ssrs.html).